# Rendering Neo4j graph output in my web browser

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a requirement to write a Python code that fetches neo4j graphical output and show it in my web browser. I have used API and wrote a Python code that display the neo4j output as JSON but I would like to have it as a graph visual output in my web browser.

Can you please help on this?

Comment: graph visualization is a whole world!... what kind of display do you need ? static or interactive ? what is it meant to show ? you need to be more specific